# java.sql.SQLException: No value specified for parameter 9

Tags: java, jdbc, sql-update

I just want to ask what I can do or a solution to this problem?
[enter image description here]` private void update_buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

```
    try{
        String StudId = Id_field.getText();
        String Lastname = lastname_field.getText();
        String Firstname = firstname_field.getText();
        String Middle_Ini = MiddleInitial_field.getText();
        String Age = age_field.getText();
        String Section = section_field.getText();
        String Address = address_field.getText();
        String Contact = contact_field.getText();

            Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
            sqlConn = DriverManager.getConnection(dataConn, username,password);
            String update ="UPDATE user_information SET ID=?, Lastname=?, Firstname=?, MiddleInitial=?, "
                    + "Age=?, Section=?, Address=?, ContactNo=? WHERE primary_Id=?";
            pst = sqlConn.prepareStatement(update);   
            
            pst.setString(1, StudId);
            pst.setString(2, Lastname);
            pst.setString(3, Firstname);
            pst.setString(4, Middle_Ini);
            pst.setString(5, Age);
            pst.setString(6, Section);
            pst.setString(7, Address);
            pst.setString(8, Contact);

            
            if (pst.executeUpdate() != -1) {
                
             UpdateDb();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Record Updated");
}
            
        }//try
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ex){
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(record_book.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE,
                 null, ex);
        }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.print(e);
        }
    }
```

Comment: how is that error message not clear? You are creating a dynamic query that takes 9 parameters, but you only provide 8

Comment: I think it's counting as 9 because of the Primary Id

Comment: pst.setString(8, Contact); -> this is your last parameter. Is that a 9 to you? You need to add one for the primary id

Comment: @AlexanderIvanchenko check the title, there's your error message

Comment: you yourself wrote it in the title "*No value specified for parameter 9*" - just count the `?` and how many values are being set -- to be even more correct, check each parameter (e.g first: `ID=?` and `setString(1, StudId)` - seems correct; second `Lastname=?` and `(2, Lastname)` - ok, it matches; ...; 8th: `ContactNo=?` and `(8, Contact)` - must be ok; 9th: `primary_Id=?` and where is it being set?)

Comment: @Stultuske I see. But the title should introduce the general problem, not the details and skipped it. Now a see that there are `9` parameters expected in the quire and only `8` provided. `primary_Id` to for the target entry is missing.

Comment: Your `WHERE` clause should perhaps be a little different. Maybe pole for something you have access to at the moment and is unique to the record you want to **update** like The Student ID. With that being said, perhaps change your `WHERE` clause to: `WHERE ID=?` then add a 9th prepared Statement: `pst.setString(9, StudId);`.

Comment: Hi I already fixed the problem from above. My problem now is that the update is not showing on the table either on the database.

Answer (score 0):

There are 9 question marks (`?`) in your prepared statement, and you need to provide a value for all of them. So, either remove the 9th question mark, or provide a value for it:

```sql
pst.setString(9, primary_Id);
```

Comment: Hi, Now i don't receive the error but when I try to update nothing happened on the table. Thanks for helping me

Comment: The value of `primary_Id` needs to be the same value as the record in the table you want to update. So, make sure you're setting the correct value (id).